# Filter Customers Table and Transaction Table to find out which customer who never did any transaction within 1 month

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 table

- Transaction (with typeof deposit and withdrawal)
- Customers

```js
var get30dayReport = `
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM TRANSACTION t1
LEFT JOIN customers t2 ON t1.customer = t2.username
WHERE TYPE = 'deposit'
  AND date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
ORDER BY `t1`.`date` DESC`
```

this is the query my friend give me before , but the report not giving the result what I wish

I wish to get a report that which customer who never did a new transaction within 1 month
and their last deposit date , and their amount which is stored inside transaction table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the result only by adding JOIN and usual date conditions because you want the condition about NOT HAVING some records so you need to use a condition with a subquery `(SELECT COUNT(*) ...)=0` or `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)`:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM TRANSACTION t1
LEFT JOIN customers t2 ON t1.customer = t2.username
WHERE t1.TYPE = 'deposit'
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) from TRANSACTION t3
       where t3.customer = t2.username
       AND t3.TYPE = 'deposit'
       AND t3.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)=0
  AND t1.date=(SELECT MAX(t4.date) from TRANSACTION t4
       where t4.customer = t2.username
         AND t4.TYPE = 'deposit')
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly thanks for your answer, but after i remove the limit 1 this show me all of my customers data, but what I want is the customer who didnt have any deposit record in last 30 day.

   example customer A made a deposit in 1/November/2022 , so it will be show in the result , and Customer B made a deposit in 31/December/2022 so it will not.

    I have around 20,000 + row in transaction(Table) and 500+ user in customer(Table)
how can I filter and match this type of requirement

Comment: You didn't mention deposit records in the post: `customer who never did a new transaction within 1 month`.

Comment: I corrected the query in the answer

Comment: thank you very much Anatoly , so if I want to add a range example 30-60 days, I should add a new line: AND t3.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)=0 below 30 day right

Comment: Yes, something like this